# Java/C: OpenJDK native tanh() implementation wrong?

Tags: java, c, math, floating-point, ieee-754

I was digging through some of the Java Math functions native C source code. Especially `tanh()`, as I was curious to see how they implemented that one.
However, [what I found](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/native/java/lang/fdlibm/src/s_tanh.c#L80) surprised me:

```
double tanh(double x) {
    ...
    if (ix < 0x40360000) {          /* |x|<22 */
        if (ix<0x3c800000)          /* |x|<2**-55 */
            return x*(one+x);       /* tanh(small) = small */
    ...
}
```

As the comment indicates, the [taylor series of tanh(x) around 0](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor%20series%20tanh(x)), starts with:

```
tanh(x) = x - x^3/3 + ...
```

Then why does it look like they implemented it as:

```
tanh(x) = x * (1 + x)
        = x + x^2
```

Which is clearly not the correct expansion, and even a worse approximation than just using `tanh(x) = x` (which would be faster), as indicated by this plot:

[image]

(The bold line is the one indicated on top. The other gray one is the `log(abs(x(1+x) - tanh(x)))`. The sigmoid is of course the `tanh(x)` itself.)

So, is this a bug in the implementation, or is this a hack to fix some problem (like numerical issues, which I can't really think of)? Note that I expect the outcome of both approaches to be exactly the same as there are not enough mantisse bits to actually perform the addition 1 + x, for x < 2^(-55).

*EDIT*: [I will include a link to the version of the code at the time of writing, for future reference, as this might get fixed.](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/c5294eda494101e62dc4c0eaa946ebe9ce60cd6b/src/share/native/java/lang/fdlibm/src/s_tanh.c#L82)

Comment: It's this kind of shit that causes rockets to explode.

Comment: Fully expect `tanh()` to be an _odd_ function, so `y = f(x) --> y = -f(-x)`.  `x + x^2` breaks that.  The only think is to maybe force a +sign on `f(-0.0)`, but that is easy to do with `tanh(x) = x+0.0;`.  IMO, an error that may not have showed itself  as `|x|<2**-55` ... or something to do with rounding flags.

Comment: Could `x*(one+x)` be a tricky way to effect `x+0.0` on the target platform?

Comment: @chux: Well, I don't think so, because, `1.0 + x`, would be equal to `1.0`. I don't know anything yet about IEEE 754 flags, but I guess that addition would cause the "inexact" flag to be set in case `x != 0`, reflecting the actual inexactness when comparing x to tanh(x). However, I'm not sure on why this would be useful, or how to test for this flag.

Comment: @chux: Ah, it seems like C and C++ have functions to test/set/clear floating point flags: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfenv/ So I guess that this is an implementation taken from C that tries to be correct with the flags. However, I don't think you can query those flags with Java.

Comment: It seems to me this may be a way to defeat compiler optimizers that are not IEEE-754 aware and readily optimize `x*1.0` into `x`, where the latter would not trigger the raising of denormal / underflow / inexact flags as intended by the former. It is impossible to know for sure, short of contacting K.C. Ng from whose `fdlibm` implementation this code likely originates. An updated version of this trick might be to use `fma (x, 1.0, -0.0)`.

Comment: Strike the "no IEEE-754 aware optimizer" part, of my previous comment. Under IEEE-754, and consequently appendix F of ISO C99, `x*1.0` is always equal to `x`. So this look very much like a way to force the raising of appropriate floating-point flags while returning `x`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under the conditions in which that code is executed, and supposing that IEEE-754 double-precision floating point representations and arithmetic are in use, `1.0 + x` will always evaluate to `1.0`, so `x * (1.0 + x)` will always evaluate to `x`.  The only externally (to the function) observable effect of performing the computation as is done instead of just returning `x` would be to set the IEEE "inexact" status flag.

Although I know no way to query the FP status flags from Java, other native code could conceivably query them.  More likely than not, however, the practical reason for the implementation is given by by these remarks in [the Javadocs for `java.StrictMath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StrictMath.html):

> To help ensure portability of Java programs, the definitions of some of the numeric functions in this package require that they produce the same results as certain published algorithms. These algorithms are available from the well-known network library netlib as the package "Freely Distributable Math Library," fdlibm. These algorithms, which are written in the C programming language, are then to be understood as executed with all floating-point operations following the rules of Java floating-point arithmetic.
>
> The Java math library is defined with respect to fdlibm version 5.3. Where fdlibm provides more than one definition for a function (such as acos), use the "IEEE 754 core function" version (residing in a file whose name begins with the letter e). The methods which require fdlibm semantics are `sin`, `cos`, `tan`, `asin`, `acos`, `atan`, `exp`, `log`, `log10`, `cbrt`, `atan2`, `pow`, `sinh`, `cosh`, **`tanh`**, `hypot`, `expm1`, and `log1p`.

(Emphasis added.)  You will note in the C source code an `#include "fdlibm.h"` that seems to tie it to the Javadoc comments.

Comment: Note that the range |x| < 2**(-55) includes denormal (subnormal) operands, and therefore this code may also raise denormal and underflow flags, in addition to the inexact flag. The reason one cannot use `x*1.0` here is because under IEEE-754 bindings for ISO C, this can be optimized to simply `x` (section F.8.2 of ISO C99), and such an assignment would not raise any floating-point flags.

Comment: @njuffa I thought that the underflow flag was only raised if the operation's result was inexact in addition to being tiny, so that this flag would never be raised by `1.0 * x`?

Comment: @PascalCuoq Good point, you may be right. If so, `x*1.0` may not be suitable independent of optimizing compilers. I do not recall all details of raising the underflow flag (that one is the most complicated one), but I seem to recall that IEEE 754-1985 (which is relevant to the FDLIBM code) allowed alternative designs for the contributing factors "tininess" and "loss of accuracy", where the former could be detected before or after rounding, and the latter did not necessarily involve inexactness.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, as I understand it, the inexact flag would never be set as a result of a multiplication by 1.0, but *neither is it cleared*.  If it is set as a result of evaluating `1.0 + x` then it will still be set after that result is multiplied by `x`.